# How can I implement this functionality with Supabase?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I'm working on a web application. Vue + Supabase.
There are two registration forms in the application. One is for regular users, the other is for special users.
Regular users can easily register, but special users must enter a special code that is generated in the admin panel, when admin click on the "add code" button, and this code must be deleted after successful registration.
How can such functionality be implemented? Deleting the code after registration is understandable - a simple trigger, adding - a simple check for the admin role (row policy). But how to implement check at registration??

In principle, there will be few users and none of them will try to hack the application, but still I don't want to make a filter at the front. Something like:

```
supabase
    .from('verif_codes')
    .select('*')
    .eq('code', this.userEnteredCode)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.data.length === 0){
            this.errors.code = true;
        } else {
            supabase.singUp(...)
        }
    });
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use Row Level Security - I would assume. Not a Supabase user here...

Comment: @madflow, Yes, I suspect it. I need to know "how exactly" to do this. Any specific help? Maybe some lesson? I searched for a long time and in vain (((

Answer (score 1):

The `supabase.signUp()` call inserts a new row in the auth.users table if it is successful. This means that you can implement what you want in a trigger attached to the `auth.users` table.

For example:

1. You can pass the code to the `options.data` parameter of the `supabase.signUp` method
2. The data inside the `options.data` parameter is stored in the  `raw_user_meta_data` column of the `auth.users` table
3. Given (1) and (2) above, you can create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the `auth.users` table and check that the code (which can be accessed like this: `NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'myCodeField'`) actually exists in the table where you store your codes (which should still be protected using RLS or some other mechanism to ensure that no one can tamper with them)
4. If the code does NOT exist, you can abort the insertion (which would essentially abort the registration) by throwing an exception (e.g. with `RAISE EXCEPTION`) or just returning NULL from the trigger function

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Points 1 and 2 are clear to me. But with point 3, everything is not so smooth for me.
When creating a trigger, I specify the users table, ok, I specify INSERT, ok, I specify BEFORE, and everything is fine here too. But at the end there is a paragraph "Choose a function to trigger".
When I click on it, I get to the list of my functions. Okay, click on "Create a new function".
Schema: auth
Return type: trigger

I add the NEW argument with the jsonb type (I don't know which one is correct).

Comment: And in the body I specify:
`NEW.raw_user_meta_data->> 'code'`
I know that this code just gets the code field from the user, but I have no idea what to write next.

and how to query the "codes" table? How is it done in supabase?

Comment: is something like that?

select * from invite_codes /* ? */
where code = USER.raw_user_meta_data->>'code'; /* ? */

if not found then /* ? */
  return null;
end if;

return true; /* ? */

Comment: Your description from the first comment sounds like you are using the Supabase dashboard - I am afraid I cannot help you much there since I don't use it (I use a regular SQL client).
NOTE, that Supabase gives you just a regular PostgreSQL database - so any query that you can run against a PostgreSQL database, you can also run against your Supabase instance.
Finally, the code you have in your last comment looks very close to what I would expect to see, so you are on the right track.